# Get Key values of the Row whose values are not Updated during Multiple row update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-returning

This is a Continuation of my previous question
[sql update for dynamic row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837016/sql-update-for-dynamic-row-number)

This time I am having an updated requirement.
I am having 2 tables 
**CraftTypes** & **EmployeeCraftTypes**.

I need to update multiple rows in the **CraftType** Table and
I was able to update it as per the answer provided by [TheGameiswar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2975396/thegameiswar)

Now there is a modification in the requirement.

In the table **CraftTypes**, there is a foreign key reference for the column ***CraftTypeKey*** with the table **EmployeeCraftsTypes**.

If there exist an entry for ***CraftTypeKey*** in the **EmployeeCrafttypes** table, then the row should not be updated.
Also the **CraftTypeKey**'s whose row values are not updated must be obtained for returning the FK_restriction status of the rows.

This is the sql query I am using.

```
            CREATE TYPE [DBO].[DEPARTMENTTABLETYPE] AS TABLE
         ( DepartmentTypeKey SMALLINT, DepartmentTypeName VARCHAR(50),DepartmentTypeCode VARCHAR(10) , DepartmentTypeDescription VARCHAR(128) )  

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateDepartmentType]

@DEPARTMENTDETAILS [DBO].[DEPARTMENTTABLETYPE] READONLY

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rowcount1 INT
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        UPDATE  D1
        SET
            D1.[DepartmentTypeName]=D2.DepartmentTypeName
           ,D1.[DepartmentTypeCode]=D2.DepartmentTypeCode
           ,D1.[DepartmentTypeDescription]=D2.DepartmentTypeDescription

        FROM 
             [dbo].[DepartmentTypes] D1
        INNER JOIN 
            @DEPARTMENTDETAILS D2
        ON 
            D1.DepartmentTypeKey=D2.DepartmentTypeKey

        WHERE
            D2.[DepartmentTypeKey] not in (select 1 from [dbo].[EmployeeDepartment] where [DepartmentTypeKey]=D2.DepartmentTypeKey)

        SET @ROWCOUNT1=@@ROWCOUNT
        COMMIT
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ROWCOUNT1=0
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH

    IF @rowcount1 =0
        SELECT  -174;
    ELSE
        SELECT  100;

    END 
    END
```

Please Help
And Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok

I think I figured out a way for it this time. I am not sure this is the right way, but its enough for me to meet the requirements.

I selected the distinct rows with FK reference from **EmployeeCraftsTypes** table as a second select query.

Now I can get the Row values which are not getting updated due to FK constraint.

This is the sql query I have used

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateCraftType]

@CRAFTDETAILS [DBO].[CRAFTTABLETYPE] READONLY

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @STATUSKEY TINYINT = (SELECT DBO.GETSTATUSKEY('ACTIVE'))
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT1 INT

    BEGIN


BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        UPDATE  C1
        SET
              [C1].[CraftTypeName]=C2.CRAFTTYPENAME
              ,[C1].[CRAFTTYPEDESCRIPTION]=C2.CRAFTTYPEDESCRIPTION
              ,[C1].[StatusKey]=C2.[StatusKey]
        FROM 
            [dbo].[CRAFTTYPES] C1
        INNER JOIN 
            @CRAFTDETAILS C2
        ON 
            C1.CRAFTTYPEKEY=C2.CRAFTTYPEKEY
        WHERE
            C2.[CRAFTTYPEKEY] NOT IN (SELECT EC.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]  from [dbo].[EmployeeCrafts] EC where EC.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]=C2.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]) 

        SET @ROWCOUNT1=@@ROWCOUNT
        COMMIT
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ROWCOUNT1=0
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH

        --SET @ROWCOUNT1 = @@ROWCOUNT

    IF @ROWCOUNT1 =0
        SELECT  -172;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  100;

        SELECT DISTINCT EC.[CRAFTTYPEKEY],'Value Already Assigned' as Reason
        FROM [DBO].[EmployeeCrafts] EC
        JOIN @CRAFTDETAILS C3
        on C3.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]=EC.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]
         WHERE EC.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]=C3.[CRAFTTYPEKEY]


    END
    END 
END
```

Now in the Web API side I can check if there is any update failure by checking the rowcount for the second table.
If the row count is more than 0, then update error message can be generated

Hope it will be helpful to someone ....